# Streaming JSON Objects From a Large Compressed File

Tags: python

I am working on a personal project which involves reading in large files of JSON objects, which consist of potentially millions of entries, which are compressed using GZip. The problem that I am having is in determining how to efficiently parse these objects line-by-line and store them in memory such that they do not use up all of the RAM on my system. It must be able to access or construct these objects at a later time for analysis. What I have attempted thus far is as follows

```
def parse_data(file):
   accounts = []
   with gzip.open(file, mode='rb') as accounts_data:
      for line in accounts_data:
         # if line is not empty
         if len(line,strip()) != 0:
            account = BytesIO(line)
            accounts.append(account)
   return accounts

def getaccounts(accounts, idx):
   account = json.load(accounts[idx])
   # creates account object using fields in account dict
   return account_from_dict(account)
```

A major problem with this implementation is that I am unable to access the same object in accounts twice without it resulting in a JSONDecodeError's being generated. I also am not sure whether or not this is the most compact way I could be doing this.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Edit: The format of the data stored in these files are as follows:

```
{JSON Object 1}
{JSON Object 2}
...
{JSON Object n}
```

Edit: It is my intention to use the information stored in these JSON account entries to form a graph of similarities or patterns in account information.

Comment: It looks like there's one JSON object per logical line of the gzipped file, correct? It's very difficult (impossible?) to randomly access data in a compressed file. Is uncompressing the entire file temporarily into an uncompressed one an option? If it is, you would only need to store the file offset where each one begins (in the uncompressed file).

Comment: @martineau Decompressing the files and storing them in memory in a compact fashion, or storing them on disk as a temporary file are both options. These files can range in size from a few MB to over 100 MB

Comment: I'm suggesting you do a combination of those things. All you really need to store in memory is where each object starts in the uncompressed file which you can easily determine while creating it (`file.tell()` returns the current file offset and the difference between it and the previous one is its length). Later on you can use that info to randomly access the object by doing a `file.seek()` to the point where it was stored in the temp file, read in the number of bytes that comprise it, and then use `json.loads()` to obtain the object). What's in memory is just this index of all the objects.

Comment: You might be surprised at what is performant and what is not. Can you tell us what you're doing with this data? Do you need all the accounts at once, do you need just certain fields, do you process things in sequential order, or build a graph, or refer from one to the next. That kind of information can help determine what will improve your speed and what will hurt you.

Comment: @AustinHastings It was my intention to construct a graph based on patterns or similarities in account information.

Comment: @martinsarif So would you need all accounts in memory to compute similarities, or just one at a time to compute some kind of hash?

Comment: @AustinHastings I suspect that I only require the object to be instantiated long enough for it to be evaluated with respect to the information already captured in the graph.

Comment: @martineau I am unfamiliar with the use of tell() and seek() for this purpose. Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: martinsarif: How about at least some feedback on the example I posted for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to randomly access JSON objects in the gzipped file by first uncompressing it into a temporary file and then using `tell()` and `seek()` to retrieve them by index — thus requiring only enough memory to hold the offsets of each one.

I'm posting this primarily because you asked me for an example of doing it in the comments...which I wouldn't have otherwise, because it not quite the same thing as [streaming data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_data). The major difference is that, unlike doing that, it gives access to all the data including being able to randomly access any of the objects at will.

Uncompressing the entire file first does introduce some additional overhead, so unless you need to be able to access the JSON object more than once, probably wouldn't be worth it. The implementation shown could probably be sped-up by caching previous loaded objects, but without knowing precisely what the access patterns will be, it hard to say for sure.

```
import collections.abc
import gzip
import json
import random
import tempfile


class GZ_JSON_Array(collections.abc.Sequence):
    """ Allows objects in gzipped file of JSON objects, one-per-line, to be
        treated as an immutable sequence of JSON objects.
    """
    def __init__(self, gzip_filename):
        self.tmpfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile('w+b')
        # Decompress a gzip file into a temp file and save offsets of the
        # start of each line in it.
        self.offsets = []
        with gzip.open(gzip_filename, mode='rb') as gzip_file:
            for line in gzip_file:
                line = line.rstrip().decode('utf-8')
                if line:
                    self.offsets.append(self.tmpfile.tell())
                    self.tmpfile.write(bytes(line + '\n', encoding='utf-8'))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.offsets)

    def __iter__(self):
        for index in range(len(self)):
            yield self[index]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """ Return a JSON object at offsets[index] in the given open file. """
        if index not in range(len(self.offsets)):
            raise IndexError
        self.tmpfile.seek(self.offsets[index])
        try:
            size = self.offsets[index+1] - self.offsets[index]  # Difference with next.
        except IndexError:
            size = -1  # Last one - read all remaining data.
        return json.loads(self.tmpfile.read(size).decode())

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.tmpfile.close()  # Allow it to auto-delete.
        except Exception:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    gzip_filename = 'json_objects.dat.gz'

    json_array = GZ_JSON_Array(gzip_filename)

    # Randomly access some objects in the JSON array.
    for index in random.sample(range(len(json_array)), 3):
        obj = json_array[index]
        print('object[{}]: {!r}'.format(index, obj))
```

Comment: martinsarif: I didn't post it. but I also wrote a version that memory-maps the temporary file which might provide better performance depending on exactly what you're doing — (see  Doug Hellmann's PyMOTW3 site article [mmap — Memory-map Files](https://pymotw.com/3/mmap/index.html) that has a  description of why).

Answer (score 0):

Hhi, perhaps use an incremental json reader such as [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/). That does not require loading the entire structure into memory at once.

Comment: IJson allows for reading in large arrays of json objects stored in files, but I do not believe it allows for reading in large collections of independent json objects such as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers in the comments, it seems like you just need to scan through the objects:

```
def evaluate_accounts(file):
    results = {}

    with gzip.open(file) as records:
        for json_rec in records:
            if json_rec.strip():
                account = json.loads(json_rec)
                results[account['id']] = evaluate_account(account)

    return results
```